# How to setup test cases with data that is not repeatable?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I come across test cases that are not repeatable. Say, one test case is to upload a file to a third-party service. The service restricts one upload for a day. So if I run the test case with a timestamp as 2012.10.10, I literally cannot rerun the test within the same day. How can we design our test case to overcome this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing isn't testing your code, but testing the third party service.

In this case you should run the test against a mock of the service, not the real thing.